# Setting text of JLabel with an array/loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, jlabel

How can I set the text of a JLabel with a loop? For example:

```
String cur[]= {"A","B","C"};
JLabel lblA,lblB,lblC;

for(i=0;i < cur.length;i++){
  lbl+cur[i].setText("something");
}
```

what should go in the "lbl+cur[i]" part so it sets the text of the JLabels?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically create variable names like that.

If you want to set the value of a label in a loop then you need to create an array of JLabels the same way you create an array of Strings.

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[cur.length];

for (int i = 0 i < cur.length; i++)
{
    labels[i] = new JLabel( cur[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of JLabels instead:

```
JLabel[] labels = {new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel()};
for ( JLabel label : labels ) {
   label.setText("something");
   panel.add(label);
}
```