# Using a Keybind and MouseInfo to get Label

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, key-bindings

This is a follow up question from my previous [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664619/setting-text-of-jlabel-with-an-array-loop)

I have two `JPanels` that have 5 `JLabels` each. When I hove the mouse over one of the `JLabels` and press the delete key, I want to print the label's text. Here is what I have tried:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeybindExample extends JPanel {

   public KeybindExample() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(firstRow(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(secondRow(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      KeyStroke delKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0);
      String delete = "delete";

      inputMap.put(delKeyStroke, delete);
      actionMap.put(delete, new DeleteAction());
   }

   private class DeleteAction extends AbstractAction {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         PointerInfo pInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
         Point ptOnScrn = pInfo.getLocation();
         int xPanel = getLocationOnScreen().x;
         int yPanel = getLocationOnScreen().y;
         int x = ptOnScrn.x - xPanel;
         int y = ptOnScrn.y - yPanel;

         Component component = getComponentAt(x, y);
         if (component != null) {
             JLabel selectedLabel = (JLabel) component;
             System.out.println("Selected Label: " + selectedLabel.getText());
          }
      }
   }
   private static JPanel firstRow(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        String [] x = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
            panel.add(label);
        }

        return panel;
   }
   private static JPanel secondRow(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        String [] x = {"6","7","8","9","10"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
            panel.add(label);
        }

        return panel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      KeybindExample mainPanel = new KeybindExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Bindings Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast to javax.swing.JLabel
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, I have a `JPanel`(KeybindExample) that contains two `JPanels`, and each of those two `JPanels` contain `JLabels`. Therefore, when I do getComponentAt(x,y) the component I'm getting is another `JPanel` which is causing the issue with the typecasting.

What I believe I need to do is to get the Component At (x,y)'s component, which would be a `JLabel`. In other words I need to go one step further. I tried the following, but it only worked for the top panel, and sometimes still returned the same error.

```
     Component component = getComponentAt(x, y);
     if (component != null) {
        JPanel selectPanel = (JPanel) component;
        Component comp = selectPanel.getComponentAt(x,y);

        if(comp != null){
           JLabel selectLabel = (JLabel) comp;
           System.out.println("Selected Label: " + selectLabel.getText());
        }
     }
  }
```

}

How can I have multiple JPanels that contain multiple JLabels but be able to have the JLabel that has the mouse hovered over's text.

Comment: *"When I hove the mouse over one of the JLabels and press the delete key, I want.."*  That sounds overly complicated (for the user).  Why not simply use `JButton` instead of the `JLabel` and make it 'do something' when the button is clicked on?

Answer (score 3):

The key question is -- how to get the *reference* to the desired JLabel at a certain point in time, here when you press the delete key. Your current solution, the one that I proposed previously, is not working because the code finds the current component relative to the KeybindExample JPanel since this is the component that you're calling the `getComponentAt()` method on. One possible solution is to call `getComponentAt()` on the JPanels that actually hold the JLabels. Another possible solution is to calculate the mouse location relative to each JLabel, and use the `contains(...)` method to see if the mouse is over one of the JLabels. To do this, you'd need to have access to all the JLabels, perhaps by putting them in a `List<JLabel>`. For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeybindExample extends JPanel {
   private List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();

   public KeybindExample() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(firstRow(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(secondRow(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      KeyStroke delKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0);
      String delete = "delete";

      inputMap.put(delKeyStroke, delete);
      actionMap.put(delete, new DeleteAction());
   }

   private class DeleteAction extends AbstractAction {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         PointerInfo pInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
         Point ptOnScrn = pInfo.getLocation();

         for (JLabel label : labelList) {
            int x = ptOnScrn.x - label.getLocationOnScreen().x;
            int y = ptOnScrn.y - label.getLocationOnScreen().y;

            if (label.contains(x, y)) {
               System.out.println("Selected Label: " + label.getText());
            }

         }
         // int xPanel = getLocationOnScreen().x;
         // int yPanel = getLocationOnScreen().y;
         // int x = ptOnScrn.x - xPanel;
         // int y = ptOnScrn.y - yPanel;
         //
         // Component component = getComponentAt(x, y);
         // if (component != null) {
         // JLabel selectedLabel = (JLabel) component;
         // System.out.println("Selected Label: " + selectedLabel.getText());
         // }
      }
   }

   private JPanel firstRow() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      String[] x = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
         labelList.add(label);
         label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
         panel.add(label);
      }

      return panel;
   }

   private JPanel secondRow() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      String[] x = { "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
         labelList.add(label);
         label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
         panel.add(label);
      }

      return panel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      KeybindExample mainPanel = new KeybindExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Bindings Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Still scratching my head over why a JList wouldn't solve this problem +1

Answer (score 3):

Despite the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987008/1795530) is really good, it quickly falls in a pitfall just because [Component#getComponentAt(int x, int y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getComponentAt%28int,%20int%29) has its limitations as you already are experiencing:

> Determines if this component or one of its immediate subcomponents
>   contains the `(x, y)` location, and if so, returns the containing
>   component. ***This method only looks one level deep. If the point `(x, y)`
>   is inside a subcomponent that itself has subcomponents, it does not go
>   looking down the subcomponent tree.***

***Note:*** remarks are mine.

IMHO you shoud follow [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (without the last S of course) principle and go with a more simple, robust and scalable approach like described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24986826/1795530). In a nutshell:

- Keep a `JLabel` class member (lets say `hoveredLabel`)
- Implement just one [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to update this class member on [mouseEntered()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) using [getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) and set this to `null` on [mouseExited()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseExited%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).
- Attach this mouse listener to all labels.
- Use key binding to remove `hoveredLabel` only if `hoveredLabel != null`